# remove last separator?

Tags: menus

using;

```
$args = array( 'menu' => 'mainmenu', 'container' => 'ul', 'menu_class' => 'span-10 clearfix', 'after'=>'/');
wp_nav_menu($args);
```

which gives me;
london/munich/artists/fairs & events/publications/news/contact/

but using the args (or similar) can i remove the  / from contact?

any help welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a completely different approach to the problem. Since the slashes may be considered to be presentational, they should not go into the HTML. Users without CSS just get to see a regular list.

You could then use CSS to restyle the list and add the slashes in between.

```
#nav li { display:inline; }
#nav li:before { content:' / '; }
#nav li:first-child:before { content:''; }
```

[**Check it out here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9PMLJ/).

Note: this will not work in IE7 and older. IE7 does support `:first-child` but `:before` only works from IE8.

Answer (score 1):

First +1 for using **blueprint css** :)

Second: Yes, separators are just presentational and shouldn't be part of the menu (screenreader using people would be confused). So here you get a simple function to add separator-css-classes or any other additional classes whereever you need them. Just modify the three vars to your needs.

And now here's the function that let you exactly target a single nav menu item in a specific location within a specific menu. You just have to modify the first three vars `$menu_location`, `$menu_name`, & `$menu_item` to your needs.

```
function wpse15844_nav_top_classes( $classes, $item ) 
{
    // EDIT HERE: This is the nav menu location slug
    $menu_location = 'top';
    // EDIT HERE: This is the nav menu name you entered in the admin-UI > Appearance > Menus (Add menu)
    $menu_name = 'Topnav';

    // Abort if we're not with the named menu
    if ( is_nav_menu( $menu_name ) !== true ) 
        return;

    if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_location ] ) )
    {
        $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_location ] );
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id );
    }

    // Abort if we're not in the specified location
    else 
        return;

    // EDIT HERE: Enter the nr. of the menu item. Currently we're adding to the last one.
    $menu_item = intval( count( $menu_items ) );

    if ( $item->menu_order == $menu_item )
    {
        $classes[] = 'span-10 clearfix';
    }
    else 
    {
        $classes[] = 'span-10 clearfix separator';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'wpse15844_nav_top_classes', 10, 2 );
```

You can then style your separator as you need it from inside your css file.

Answer (score 0):

If you can move the `/` to before the links ( `'before' => '/'` instead of `'after' => '/'` ), that would make it much easier to filter out; you could do it like this:

```
function wpse15844_nav_separator_filter( $output, $item, $depth, $args ){
    global $wpse15844_nav_separators;
    if( !isset( $wpse15844_nav_separators ) )
        $wpse15844_nav_separators = array();
    if( isset( $wpse15844_nav_separators[$depth] ) && $wpse15844_nav_separators[$depth] )
        return $output;
    $wpse15844_nav_separators[$depth] = true;
    return substr( $output, strlen( $args->before ) );
}

add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'wpse15844_nav_separator_filter', 10, 4 );
```

Answer (score 0):

And this is how you should be able to add the `/` after (even if not recommended). For some reason this doesn't work as expected, even if i get the right `$args` when i `print_r` it (see `#`-uncommented code). It adds to the first (in my testcase) instead of the last element.

@John P Bloch @Geert - Could you pls give this a try and tell me if this works wrong for you too? Thanks!

```
function wpse15844_nav_top_args( $output, $item, $depth, $args ) 
{
    // EDIT HERE: This is the nav menu location slug.
    $menu_location = 'top';
    // EDIT HERE: This is the nav menu name you entered in the admin-UI > Appearance > Menus (Add menu).
    $menu_name = 'Topnav';

    // Abort if we're not with the named menu
    if ( is_nav_menu( $menu_name ) !== true ) 
        return;

    // You won't need the following if statement if you're not targeting the last menu item.
    if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_location ] ) )
    {
        $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_location ] );
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id );
    }

    // Abort if we're not in the specified location - If you're not searching for the last item, you won't need this one too.
    else 
        return;

    // EDIT HERE: Enter the nr. of the menu item in the second line inside eg. intval( 3 ). Currently we're adding to the last one.
    $menu_item = count( $menu_items );
    $menu_item = intval( $menu_item );

    // Add the class
    if ( $item->menu_order !== $menu_item )
    {
        $args->after = '/';
        # echo '<pre>'; print_r( $args ); echo '</pre>';
    }
    else 
    {
        $args->after = '';
        # echo '<pre>'; print_r( $args ); echo '</pre>';
    }

    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'wpse15844_nav_top_args', 10, 4 );
```