# Using separator with wp_list_categories

Tags: categories

How can I use separator with wp_list_categories using inline list? In [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) they say `(string) Separator between links. Default '<br />'.`
Well I guess that means I could use HTML right? I was thinking about using `&middot;` to connect items like I have in image but nothing happens.

[image]

```
wp_list_categories(array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'child_of' => get_cat_ID('mycatname'),
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'show_option_none' => false,
    'separator' => '&middot;'
));
```

I tried putting something else as separator, but nothing happens so I wonder if it even works or am I missing something?

```
<ul>
<?php 
    $arr = wp_list_categories(array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of' => get_cat_ID('Biljke'),
        'hide_empty' => true,
        'show_option_none' => false,
        'separator' => '-----',
    ));
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the last version of WordPress? `separator` parameter is introduced just some subversions ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the default of the `style` input parameter is `list`.

Try something like:

```
'separator' => '&middot;',
'style'     => 'separator',  // something else than 'list'
```

to override the `list` default.

We can see why this happens by peeking into the `Walker_Category::start_el()` method. There we have the following:

```
if ( 'list' == $args['style'] ) {
    // ...cut ...
 } elseif ( isset( $args['separator'] ) ) {
     $output .= "\t$link" . $args['separator'] . "\n";
 } else {
     $output .= "\t$link<br />\n";
 }
```

Comment: Downvote, sorry, but this also adds the separator after the last term. I guess you could use implode to fix this but not sure how.

Comment: @Dev that sounds like a core bug. You could grab and edit the returned output with "echo" argument as false. Check e.g. [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/646/wordpress-remove-br-separator-from-last-item-in-wp-list-categories) from the Related list, here to right.

Comment: Seems to be a core bug to me. Maybe someone should file a core bug report.

Comment: feel free to report that bug :-)

Comment: Thank you, i might if i can work out a patch or fix. Not sure what its called.

Comment: yes a patch, it should be as a diff form. First make sure it has not been reported before. If it has and is open then work from that ticket. Then it's good to check out eg  Slack, it has weekly meetings for new contributors. I recommend contributing but note that some tickets can take long time to resolve. Good luck.